# RSK correspondence for sum of two matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux

The celebrated RSK correspondence ([see Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted%E2%80%93Knuth_correspondence)) assigns to each integer $X$ matrix a pair of Young tableaux $P$ and $Q$. Now suppose that we have three integer matrices $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, with the corresponding pairs $(P_1,Q_1)$, $(P_2,Q_2)$, and $(P_3,Q_3)$.

Let $X_3 = X_1 + X_2$. What is the relationship between $(P_3,Q_3)$ and $\{(P_1,Q_1),(P_2,Q_2)\}$? Can one derive $(P_3,Q_3)$ in a formal way from the other pairs? For example, it easy to see that the content of $P_3$ is the union of the contents of $P_1$ and $P_2$. Is it true that $P_3$ is some formal sum of the Young tableaux $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: One place to start is when $X_1$ is just a matrix with a single non-zero entry.
There is a type of commutative formal sum on SSYT, namely to elementwise add the corresponding entries in the GT-patterns, see https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/gtpatterns.htm#gtpatternsAsSSYT for this correspondence

Comment: I don't think they'll be an easy answer, but it might be helpful to use the "toggle" description of RSK for this problem: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~shopkins/docs/rsk.pdf